# OpenCV build error: does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt

Tags: opencv, cmake

I am following this guide to build an optimized version of OpenCV for android:
https://medium.com/@tomdeore/opencv-on-android-tiny-with-optimization-enabled-932460acfe38

Step 4:

- I downloaded OpenCV from Github (https://github.com/opencv/opencv)
- I run:

  ```
  fabio@fabio-XPS-15-9560:~/Software/opencv-3.4.9$ mkdir build
  fabio@fabio-XPS-15-9560:~/Software/opencv-3.4.9$ cd build/
  fabio@fabio-XPS-15-9560:~/Software/opencv-3.4.9/build$ cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../platforms/android/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_STL=gnustl_shared -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=23
  ```

But I got this error:

```
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/fabio/Software/opencv-3.4.9/build" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, in your [linked](https://medium.com/@tomdeore/opencv-on-android-tiny-with-optimization-enabled-932460acfe38) build guide, the `cmake` command ends with a `..` telling CMake to run on the parent directory:

```
cmake  \
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../platforms/android/android.toolchain.cmake\
-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_shared \
-DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=23 ..
```

You are running CMake from the `build` directory, which is incorrect. You want to run on the parent directory, which *does* contain a CMakeLIsts.txt file.